# How to find city name from latitude and longitude in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, analytics, postgis

I have a database which has latitudes and longitudes of various properties stored. I want to find out, which city does each of these properties belong to (all properties are in the US).

Comment: Please try on google MAP API

Comment: How do I integrate the Google MAP API in my SQL query?

Comment: First of all get lat or long using SQL query. and then pass lat or long in this API
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$lat.','.$long.'&sensor=true')

Comment: My target here is to do the entire process using SQL (if that's possible), without using any other scripting language. 

So, my question goes back to, how do I make API calls using SQL?

Comment: You can do this using only SQL if you load the tiger extension in Postgis (without Google Maps). Follow the instructions on this page: https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#install_tiger_geocoder_extension and this one: https://postgis.net/docs/Reverse_Geocode.html

Comment: You need to have city boundaries in order to find for which city the given point belongs. If you don't have city boundaries you can download it from `OSM`. Then you can check on which city boundary given point belongs to using `st_contains` method.

Answer (score 3):

Talking about Postgresql, first of all you need to get a data of US cities boundaries shape file.  Possible sites are

```
https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html  
https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html
https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=cities
```

After that import data into postgres. I am assuming that your properties data is already stored in postgres. Make sure the SRID geometry type of cities boundaries is 4326. if not, you can convert it easily with ST_transform function.

Finally, to check which city some specific lat/long  falls in, you need to convert the lat/long into point geometry and check against the cities data. e.g it would be some thing like this

```
SELECT c.city_name FROM cities_boundaries AS c, properties AS p
WHERE ST_CONTAINS(c.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p.longitude, p.latitude), 4326))
```